# Java 11 reflection

Tags: java, reflection, java-11

I need a general means to determine if reflective access is allowed to an object member.  In Java 8, if the member is public and the class is public, then reflective access is allowed.  In Java 11, this is no longer true.  So how can I determine if reflective access is allowed to an object member in Java 11?  Here is some sample code illustrating the problem:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import javax.net.SocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public class Refl {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //System.out.println(sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.class); // doesn't work
        SocketFactory sf = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLSocketFactory.class.getMethod("getDefaultCipherSuites").invoke(sf);
        Class cls = sf.getClass();
        System.out.println(cls);
        System.out.println(Modifier.isPublic(cls.getModifiers()));
        Method m = cls.getMethod("getDefaultCipherSuites");
        System.out.println(m);
        System.out.println(Modifier.isPublic(m.getModifiers()));
        m.invoke(sf);  // here is the issue
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

Comment: IllegalAccessException seems like a good way to detect it.  Out of curiosity, why do you need to do this?

Comment: Can you please clarify the changes you’re referring to for Java 11? I’m not familiar. And what is the _issue_ in your code?

Comment: You know you can just do `sf.getDefaultCipherSuites()`, right?  Reflection is not needed.

Comment: If something isn't public, maybe you should find out how to use the public API instead of hacking around it? That should make your code both easier and less brittle.

Answer (score 1):

`Method` extends `Executable` and `Executable` extends [`AccessibleObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html).

`AccessibleObject` provides a method named [`canAccess`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#canAccess(java.lang.Object)) that you can use for this purpose:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import javax.net.SocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public class Refl {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //System.out.println(sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.class); // doesn't work
        SocketFactory sf = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLSocketFactory.class.getMethod("getDefaultCipherSuites").invoke(sf);
        Class cls = sf.getClass();
        System.out.println(cls);
        System.out.println(Modifier.isPublic(cls.getModifiers()));
        Method m = cls.getMethod("getDefaultCipherSuites");
        System.out.println(m);
        System.out.println(m.canAccess(sf));// check here
        m.invoke(sf);  // here is the issue
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but no, the call to canAccess() itself produces a warning.

Comment: Here is what happened with the code: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iGEnxPA2v_amuFXWO092oNMOgiLY2lff2bYa8n1qrJI/edit?usp=sharing -

Comment: @WillLin try running with `--illegal-access=deny` or with the most recent JDK, where this is the default